# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: abstract

This is probably not a duplicate question. I have checked on this error am getting though all problems seem to have a table issue. I do not have a table in my entire document. This error comes from the line where I declare the `\abstract` environment. The line gets highlighted after compiling. I am using the `article class`. It doesn't stop the document from compiling though the error speaks of a problem I may be having. Here is what I have as MWE

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
        urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
        linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
        citecolor   = blue %Colour of citations
    }
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \author{George & Idi}
    \title{Medical Haemorrhage}
    % Removing hyphens from the document
    \tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

    \begin{document}
        \maketitle  
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{abstract}
        This has been quite an unprecedented cause of death.
    \end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

Just by the `\begin{abstract}` I get the warning.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example code?

Comment: `\tolerance=1
    \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
    \hyphenpenalty=10000
    \hbadness=10000` ouch, really? especially the last one which means you don't want to be warned no matter how bad the typesetting is?

Comment: @David Carlisle, not sure am learning much from your comment in relation to my problem. Are you saying I am getting the error because of including the lines of code above or is the `\hbadness=10000` such a bad choice to suppress automatic hyphenation?

Comment: setting `\hbadness=` does not change the typesetting at all it just says don't warn about boxes that have a badness of less than 10000, but as that is the maximum badness it just suppresses all warnings.

Comment: Quite astonishing. The MWE with shorter tittle seems to work. The `\maketitle` in my wild view could be the cause. Disabling the command makes the document go with no error but the title not generated. The exact title is quite long and probably conflicting with my desire to suppress the hyphenation. Out of curiosity, I have moved the `\maketitle` command just below the `\title{}` command and the error appeared in the line that follows. Quite confusing.

Comment: Yes it does. There are two Authors so I have, `\author{George kariuki\thanks{University of Cape Town, South Africa} & Idi Jackson\thanks{Kenyatta University, Nairobi}}`. I tried to stick to a simple MWE to avoid a bulky outlook. Would be badly embarrassed for not having included the entire of this.

Comment: I edited the example so it demonstrated the error, and deleted most of the earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

An unescaped `&` can only be used in alignments. To produce a `&` character in text you need `\&` but to separate multiple authors, which (finally) you mentioned in comments, in `article` class you should use `\and`

```
\author{George kariuki\thanks{University of Cape Town, South Africa}
       \and
       Idi Jackson\thanks{Kenyatta University, Nairobi}}.
```

Comment: Thank you. This has solved my problem. One more request please, how do I make the second author appear in the next line. As is, they appear in the same line. Am really sorry for not been clear before. I am a newbie in Latex with an undivided devotion to learn.

Comment: @GeorgeKariuki no harm done, but next time please actually run latex over your example document _before_ posting to check it is an example of the problem you want to ask about:-)  article class has very simple author formatting, most journal classes completely re-implement that anyway.  You can redefine `\and` to have `\par` instead of horizontal space eg `\def\and{\end{tabular}\par\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}` in your preamble

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @David Carlisle !!!! I am sorted for now.